# url in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is a javascript geo-target code:

```
<script src='http://promos.fling.com/geo/txt/location.php?testip='></script>
```

Is possible add the results of it in the end of URL?

```
<a href="http://www.example.net/?q=Fairfield, CT ">Fairfield, CT</a>
```

The javascript result put after ?q=

Thanks!

Comment: can you please elaborate what you are looking for???

Comment: What does the script return? How have you impemented it so far?

Comment: according to you question. You have to encode url.

Comment: It's possible to get the url query using javascript and it's possible to place it into the script tag. Can you show your attempts of doing this? You can also use PHP to do this so you have the option of php or javascript.

Comment: This will return Fairfield CT: http://promos.fling.com/geo/txt/location.php?testip=3.255.255.255 - What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The url only returns `document.write("Fairfield, CT");`  if you have something else in place for the script tag to return something else can you please include this as it would be relevant source to your question. Until then I cannot help you at all. When i run the script tag with that src I get the follow error in the console `GET http://promos.fling.com/geo/txt/location.php?testip= net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT`

Comment: If you would like to use geo data maxmind have an API in place here- http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/javascript/

Comment: Please read this article about this site http://community.websense.com/blogs/securitylabs/archive/2012/05/03/widespread-malware-abuses-unsecured-geolocation-service-of-adult-website.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a value to `location.search`. Anything you assign gets placed in front of the `?`. You may need additional parsing to extract or append specific values and reconstruct it to form a query string. Note that the page will refresh when doing so.